# CacheControl JAX-RS public directive

Tags: java, jax-rs, cache-control

I try to set the `public` directive whith the `javax.ws.rs.core.CacheControl` class (JAX-RS)

For example : `Cache-Control : public, max-age= 1000`

But this piece of code doesn't create the `public` directive :

```
Response.ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok(entity);

CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl();
cacheControl.setPrivate(false);
cacheControl.setMaxAge(1000);

rb.cacheControl(cacheControl);
return rb.build();
```

Comment: Where do you use this? In what part of your code?

Comment: in a Jersey Rest API service with a `ResponseBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting private to false via `cacheControl.setPrivate(false)` does not mean that it should be cached `public`. There's also a `no-cache` token.
As `CacheControl` has no method for setting the `public` token you need to do it manually:

```
CacheControl cacheControl = CacheControl.valueOf("public, max-age=1000")
```

Comment: Ok but what is the benefit of using cachecontrol if i have to specify the string values ? Should me more simple to use `reponseBuilder.header("cache-control", "public, max-age=...")` right ?. The javadoc of the class says that it respect the cache specification so it's weird to not have this feature.

Comment: One benefit could be if you use some helper methods which provide you some custom Cache-Control headers used from many resources... I don't know why the CacheControl class does not support all tokens. Your example produces the same header so choose what you like.

Comment: The max-age value you fill in here, is this millisecond or second? regards

Comment: max-age is counted in seconds.